# Activemq broker url

Tags: url, jms, activemq-classic

Do both of these urls work the same way?

There is // after failover: in the second one.
Does it load balance if there are multiple ips?

```
    failover:(tcp://192.168.1.111:61616)?jms.useAsyncSend=true&initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectAttempts=-1



   failover://(tcp://192.168.1.111:61616)?jms.useAsyncSend=true&initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectAttempts=-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, either of the URIs should parse equivalently in the ActiveMQ client and the client would try each IP or Host in the inner failover transport URI in order to connect.  The client cannot load balance as it doesn't know about other clients, but there are some options to get the broker to do some balancing by rejecting or diverting client connections.  Refer to the documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks Bish. We have two java clients - one using 1.6 and the other using 1.7. Java 1.6 is having issue where in jmsTemplate.send is not returning but no error.

Comment: That has nothing to do with this particular question as far as I can tell.

Comment: Was wondering if double slash after failover:// can cause any issue

Comment: No, either one works, as I said in my answer.  Updated for added clarity